# package on sys.path, with init importing names, can be used internally, but not from outside it

Tags: python, package, pythonpath

I have a package my_scripting_library I want to use anywhere on machine. It has an init.py:

```
from silo_functions import *
```

and looks like

```
my_scripting_library
  -__init__.py
  -silo_functions.py
  -test_stuff.py
```

test_stuff.py looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from silo_functions import *

lines = read_lines('filepath.py')

print lines
```

in bashrc:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:$LIBRARY"
```

where LIBRARY is a correct filepath to my_scripting_library

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: sys.path
Out[2]: 
['',
 '/usr/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml-3.3.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/home/cchilders/scripts/python/my_scripting_library',
...
 '/home/cchilders/.ipython']
```

running test_stuff with `from .silo_functions import *` causes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_stuff.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .silo_functions import *
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

running test_stuff with `from my_scripting_library.silo_functions import *` causes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test_stuff.py", line 3, in <module>
    from my_scripting_library.silo_functions import *
ImportError: No module named my_scripting_library.silo_functions
```

but running test_stuff with `from silo_functions import *` works:

*it prints the lines*

Of course I can't use this package from other folders, which is the real issue- I don't want to be forced into throwing all scripts in this one place. This is causing huge problems as I am constantly reusing dozens of functions each script, and over 5 tutorials on making a folder a python package never have worked yet. Why is something on the python path with an init not a package? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it is because you've added '.../python/*my_scripting_library*'  to your path. But there are no *'my_scripting_library.py'* at this folder.

If you want to use 'my_scripting_library.silo_functions', try to add **'/home/cchilders/scripts/python'** (not '/home/cchilders/scripts/python/my_scripting_library') to path. 
Because 'my_scripting_library' is *module*. Python will find this folder, find  `__init__.py` in this folder and mark it as module.

Comment: ty alexey, but not I try to use `my_scripting_library.silo_functions` and get

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./make_graph.py", line 5, in <module>
    from my_scripting_library.silo_functions import *
ImportError: No module named my_scripting_library.silo_functions

I have multiple function silos, why can't I use the full pathname now?

Comment: I've created a folder '/home/anth/test/module_1'. In 'test' folder: 
`$ ls module_1` returns `__init__.py package1.py`
then in python: 
`import sys;
sys.path.append(/home/anth/test/) """not /home/anth/test/module1""";
import module_1.package1`;
And it works. May be I don't understand your problem...

Comment: I had changed bashrc and forgot to source a particular terminal. ty